# how to convert this code to use lambda and stream api

Tags: java

how can we use lambda and stream api in this scenario

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(("test.txt"))));
String line = ""; String[] words;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    words = line.split(" ");
    for(String word : words){
        if(map.containsKey(word)){
            map.put(word, map.get(word)+1);
        }else{
             map.put(word, 1);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: as a sidenote: SO is not a coding service or a teaching platform - it's a question-and-answer site. also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438097/convert-method-to-java-8-lambda

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert method to java 8 lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438097/convert-method-to-java-8-lambda)

Comment: Sorry Thomas, I was just started learning lambda and streams so i put this question... Thank you..

Comment: Well, imo the best way to learn something is to read up on it and try it yourself first. That way you'll be able to combine the knowledge of what the code should do (it's your code so you should know that) and the application of the available api on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer the below code starting with `bufferedReader.stream()` and follow the inline comments:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(("test.txt"))));

br.lines()//get stream from BufferedReader
  .map(line -> line.split(" "))//split lines to array
  .flatMap(stream -> Arrays.stream(stream))//convert array to stream
  .collect(Collectors.toMap( s -> s, s -> 1,Integer::sum ));//collect stream to Map
```

Comment: Try `.collect( Collectors.toMap( s -> s, s -> 1, Integer::sum ) )` after `flatMap(...)` for even more lambdas and streams :)

Comment: Really good point, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly you are just counting the occurrence of individual words in the file. If that's correct:

```
Map<String, Long> wordCount = br.lines()
    .flatMap(l -> Arrays.stream(l.split(" "))
    .collect(groupingBy(w -> w, counting());
```